# Borel subsets of the unit square

Tags: measure-theory, descriptive-set-theory

Let $I^2:=[0,1]^2\subseteq \mathbb{R}^2$ be the closed unit square in the plane. Open and closed subsets of $I^2$ are Borel measurable for trivial reasons. Also, every set obtained from open and closed subsets of $I^2$ by taking at most a countable number of unions, intersections and complements is also Borel measurable.

My question is: are there Borel measurable subsets of $I^2$ which are *not* of the type just described?

Thank you.

Comment: Are you asking whether by taking countable unions, intersections and countable complements successively you can get all Lebesgue measurable subsets of $I^2$ from open sets? [That's not even true for $I$.](http://planetmath.org/encyclopedia/ALebesgueMeasurableButNonBorelSet.html)

Comment: @t.b.: Edited, thanks!

Comment: @Willie: Thanks! I missed the notification of the edit (before it was a duplicate of what I linked to). I removed the possible duplicate link: why don't you close and re-open?

Comment: @t.b. good idea. @ All: closing a re-opening to clear the votes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to be careful when you say "at most a countable number".  Your answer is "YES" but you have to go up the countable ordinals... Let $\cal A_0$ be the collection of all closed sets.  For any ordinal $\eta$, let $\cal A_{\eta+1}$ be the collection of all countable unions of sets from $\cal A_\eta$, together with their complements.  If $\lambda$ is a limit ordinal, let $\cal A_\lambda = \bigcup_{\eta<\lambda} \cal A_\eta$.  Then, in fact, every Borel set lies in $\cal A_\eta$ for some countable ordinal $\eta$.  But $\cal A_\eta \ne \cal A_\zeta$ if $\eta \ne \zeta$ are countable ordinals.

Answer (score 0):

By definition, a Borel measurable set is a set in the Borel sigma algebra, which on a topological space is **defined** to be the [collection of all sets that can be formed by taking countable union, countable intersection, and relative complementation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Borel_set) from the open sets.

So tautologically, there are no other sets that is Borel measurable.

If however, you are looking for *completions* of the Borel measurable sets (for example, the Lebesgue measurable sets), then the answer could become more interesting. (See [the question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/20421/) t.b. linked to.)

Comment: No need to link Wikipedia. I have described the hierarchy many times, as well others, right here on the site.

Comment: @Asaf: feel free to edit and improve (with a proper link).

Comment: But that would violate my usual approach of being lazy, yet complaining in the comments!! :-)