# Lebesgue and Borel Measurable

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, measure-theory

> If a real-valued function on $R$ is measurable with respect to the
>   $\sigma$-algebra of Lebesgue measurable sets, is it necessarily
>   measurable with respect to the Borel measurable space ($R$, $B(R)$)?

I don't think so. Is there a counter example that would be sufficient to show that there isn't?

Comment: Which sigma-algebra(s) on the source set?

Comment: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/20421/lebesgue-measurable-but-not-borel-measurable

Comment: A simple counterexample is the characteristic function of any non-Borel-measurable, Lebesgue-measurable set.

Comment: the $\sigma$-algebra of Lebesgue measurable sets are just the completion of Borel measurable sets.

Comment: See problem 35 in Chapter 1 of Real Analysis by E.M. Stein. There is an explicit construction.

Answer (score 2):

I am adding an answer to get this question off the 'unanswered' list.

**Notation:** Let $\mathcal{L}$ and $\mathcal{B}_{\mathbb{R}}$ be the set of Lebesgue measurable sets and Borel measurable sets, respectively.

The answer to your question is 'no'. Take a Lebesgue measurable set $E$ that is not Borel measurable (such sets exist: see [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/141017/lebesgue-measurable-set-that-is-not-a-borel-measurable-set?rq=1)). Consider the characteristic function $\chi_{E}: \mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}$ defined by
$$
\chi_{E} = \begin{cases}
1 & \textrm{ if } x\in E \\
0 & \textrm{ if } x\notin E
\end{cases}
$$
Then $\chi_{E}$ is $(\mathcal{L}, \mathcal{B}_{\mathbb{R}})$-measurable (i.e. Lebesgue measurable) because it is characteristic function of a measurable set.

But $\chi_{E}$ is *not* $(\mathcal{B}_{\mathbb{R}}, \mathcal{B}_{\mathbb{R}})$-measurable (i.e. Borel measurable). For example, $$\chi_{E}^{-1}\left(\frac{1}{2}, \frac{3}{2}\right)=E\notin\mathcal{B}_{R}$$

**Remark.** I am using notation consistent with Folland's *Real Analysis: Modern Techniques and Their Applications.*