# Is there a non Borel set which construction does not use the axiom of choice?

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

The construction of the Vitali set does use the axiom of choice. Is there any set which is better imaginable and not borel?

Comment: See here https://mathoverflow.net/questions/32720/non-borel-sets-without-axiom-of-choice

Comment: For examples of "better imaginable" non-borel sets, you might look [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/166784/set-in-mathbbr-which-is-not-a-borel-set). Even if you don't like the examples there, it links to many more examples! As an example to leave here, it is well known (for a certain definition of "well known") that continuous images of borel sets often aren't borel! This is a famous mistake made by Lebesgue, and the relevant sets are now called [analytic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Analytic_set) if you want to look further into this.